# Regular expression help

Tags: regex, xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to transform a XML in to flat text. One of the node has the following content and I need to extract the string that appears before the text "fail"
I was planning to use the analyze-string function and having trouble creating the regular expression for it. I tried to see if I could use the lookahead pattern but unable to do so.

Can someone tell what would be the regular expression for extracting the text within square brackets before the text "fail":

Text

```
[[2500, 4500]] fail(expected [[2100, 3000, 4000, 5000, 5400, 6000, 8000, 10000]])
```

Final output

```
[2500, 4500]
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a one-liner XPath 1.0 solution, and of course, an XSLT 1.0 solution that don't use RegEx at all. :) Explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/\[(\[.+?\])\] fail/` and get `$1`.

Comment: Thanks, the above regex includes the text fail in it. Is there a way to exclude it and also there are 2 levels of square brackets, I was hoping I could just have the inner level. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure. Use that regex and take the first catch, `$1`.

Comment: I can provide an example if you tell me what programming language you're using.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do this even in XSLT 1.0 (as a single XPath 1.0 expression) without regular expressions**:

```
substring(substring(normalize-space(substring-before(.,' fail')), 2),
          1,
          string-length(substring(
                           normalize-space(substring-before(.,' fail')), 
                           2)
                        ) -1
           )
```

Because your goal is to do this in XSLT, you can define variables for the components of this complex expression and get a simple and easily understandable code:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vStart" select=
       "normalize-space(substring-before(.,' fail'))"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vnormString" select=
     "normalize-space($vStart)"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vLen" select="string-length($vnormString)"/>

    "<xsl:value-of select="substring($vnormString, 2, $vLen -2)"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>[[2500, 4500]] fail(expected [[2100, 3000, 4000, 5000, 5400, 6000, 8000, 10000]]) </t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
"[2500, 4500]"
```

**Explanation**: Use of the standard XPath 1.0 functions:  `substring()`, `substring-before()`, `normalize-space()` and `string-length()`